# no alerts are visible in wso2 3.0.0 APIM admin portal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

for alters we have done following configurations
analytics worker yaml file

extension:
name: email
namespace: sink
properties:
username: ***@gmail.com
address: ***@gmail.com
password: ****@12

analytics.solutions:
APIM-alerts.enabled: true

in publisher->settings--- analytics response time is confiured at publisher to 1 milisec

when hit the api no alerts in admin-> alerts section

any thoughts?
am i missing something?

Comment: .ApimAbnormalResponseTimeAlert; --------no data in this table

Comment: this step is also done Go to the <API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/resources/apim-analytics/ directory. Copy the APIM_ALERT_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION.siddhi file and paste it in the <API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/wso2/worker/deployment/siddhi-files directory.